# Primefaces messages for validation and growl for the rest

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a JSF page with primefaces and I would like to use p:messages for the messages of the input validations and a Growl element for the rest of the things like notifications, errors ...

At the moment I have a Growl with attribute for and I'm sending notifications with this for attribute.

The problem is that I don't know which for attribute I have to put in the p:messages component. If I left it as null the notification messages are showing in Growl and on p:messages.

Here you can see an example of my JSF.

```
<p:growl id="growlNotifyNewReg" for="growlNotificationsNewRegister"
                         showSummary="true" 
                         showDetail="true"
                         autoUpdate="true"/>

<h:outputText value="Validado"/>
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="checkValidado" value="#{}" required="true"/>

<h:outputText value="Temperatura (ºC)"/>
<p:inputText id="Temperatura" value="#{}" required="true">
      <f:validateDoubleRange minimum="-50" maximum="60" />
      <f:convertNumber maxFractionDigits="1" />
</p:inputText>

<!-- Other inputs... -->

<p:messages showSummary="true" showDetail="true" redisplay="false"/>
```

When I want to send a notification I do like this.

```
FacesMessage facesMsg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "summary", "details");
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("growlNotificationsNewRegister", facesMsg);
```

This code sends messages to Growl component but also to messages component because it doesn't have for attribute. I want to know which attribute I have to put in messages component to show only the validations messages of the form.

As you can see I put redisplay attribute to false. Can I put multiple ids in the for attribute of the p:messages?

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example works as you want, you can change it according to your code :

**in .xhtml**

```
<h:form prependId="false"> 
     <p:growl id="growl" for="msg" showDetail="true" sticky="true" />  
     <p:panel header="Growl">  
     <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">  
        <p:outputLabel for="msg"  value="Message:" />   
        <p:inputText id="msg"  value="#{growlView.message}" required="true" />
        <p:outputLabel for="msg2" value="Message2:" />
        <p:inputText id="msg2" value="#{growlView.message2}" required="true" />  
     </h:panelGrid>  
     <p:commandButton value="Save" actionListener="#{growlView.saveMessage}" update="growl" />  
     </p:panel> 
     <p:messages id="messages" for="msg2" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" closable="true" />
</h:form>
```

in the `for` attribute for both `<p:growl>` and `<p:messages>` you can add whatever Ids you want just like `for="id1 id2 .."`

**in bean**

```
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

@ManagedBean
public class GrowlView {
    private String message;
    private String message2;

    // setters / getters

    public void saveMessage() {
        FacesMessage facesMsg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "summary", "details");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("msg", facesMsg);
    }
}
```